# GoogleMaps - dynamic input of `google.maps.Map(<dynamic>, mapOptions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So to create a google map I normally do something like:

`new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my-map'), mapOptions);`

But I need something a bit more flexible because now I have more than one map on the page. I tried something like:

`new google.maps.Map($(map).find('.my-map'), mapOptions);`

But I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined`

I've looked into [document.getElementByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) but I'm not sure how to have it search the target set that I'm iterating through. Nor do I know if I have to do something weird since I'm working with jQuery objects.

I'm guessing that I cant use a jQuery object in there. I'm new to the API so any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo and behold I actually had to do:

```
var mapElement = map[0].$map.get(0);  
new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be a DOM element not a JQuery array.

```
new google.maps.Map($(map).find('.my-map')[0], mapOptions);
```